# Whenever I use "php artisan migrate" in command prompt. I see the following error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I don't how to deal with this error. I searched a lot about it, but couldn't find anything related to the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to create database and configure in config/database.php file